# [L4, F/W]How can I deal with SPEED?

Tags: firewall, juniper, switching, speed

I have a problem about Speed when accessing web servers..

**[Circumstances]**
Everything is OK, every packet flows well.
However, now I have focused on the speed...
That is, connection is ok

**[Issues]**
Whenever I connect or access the web servers, the access speed markedly slow.

However, it is fast sometimes...
That is, slow, fast, slow, fast --- continuous

**[The data]**
First, please see the below network structure.
[image]

**[The things that I want to know]**
As you can see the data, the structure is not complicated.
To tell the truth, I don't know what device is the problem.
and I also don't know what can I see in order to fix it?

I just want to know whether device's problem.
If so, how can I control it.

Regards,
SK

--------------------modified---------------------

I captured it with wireshark.
As you can see the below capture, it showed Retransmission message.
However, the frequency was very low.

If network is very good condition, only one retransmission is now showed??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a strategy:

Start by capturing a web session with Wireshark when the response is slow.  Are you seeing timeouts/retransmissions?

If you see retransmissions, then you are losing packets somewhere.  Look at your switch interfaces for errors or drops.

If not, it may be the web server.  Is it the web server that's slow, or is it the DNS server?

Check your firewall logs to see if there's any important information there.

Comment: You mean that I should start capturing at PC which is sending the message to Web server??

Comment: Yes, that's where I would start.

Comment: Thank you expert.
One more question!..
Then, actually, I don't know well about wireshark.
Can you explain how can type the word at Filter tap?

For example, ip.addr==192.168.10.119
Please contact me sir..

Comment: You said : Is it the web server or dns server I answer : It is web server

Comment: I modified the post 
I added a part of packet from wireshark.
Can you look into it?

Comment: Could you please answer...ㅠ_ㅠ